# Repeating headers in a 2010 DVWP for printing

Tags: development, data-view-web-part

I have a DVWP with several hundred rows.  I have the print view set up correctly.  The format looks good.  The one requirement I have and cannot find a solution for is to make the column headers repeat and print on every page.  Does anyone have any insight how to make this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather difficult to establish a general procedure that should work particularly without enough details. We did managed to do something using CSS @media print attributes as follows:

1. The actual DVWP is showing as table. You would decide which rows (or
   entire section), e.g. thead in our case (replace with appropriate
   CSS selector for your class). In our case we had to introduce the
   thead section as SharePoint only generates a single TR for the
   heading of the table.
2. We've added the following CSS specifications :

   @media print { thead {display:table-header-group;}}